# Poor animation performance in Firefox when large background image is present

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2, and jQuery Tools 1.2.5 to animate an accordion in my site's navigation. In testing it in Chrome and Safari the animations are smooth and very much to my liking. In Firefox 3.6.3 I see an unacceptable level of choppiness to the point where I would say there are only 2 frames in the animation. The content of the page sits in a containing div where the navigation and other elements exist. I've tried moving around the libraries to see if any one piece is causing the slow down but the only thing that has made a noticeable improvement is when I change the background image of my body element to a solid color (currently it is a rather large image (jpg) which i'm pretty sure is the culprit). The animation still isn't great but it is nearing acceptable levels. Is there anything that I can do to improve the animation in firefox? Because of design purposes we need to have the background image in the body element (or some other element underneath everything). Thanks for reading!

Comment: Are you using transparency anywhere (other than 0 and 100)? Do you have PNGs with alpha transparency?

Comment: Yes, there are transparent pngs on the site but they are elsewhere on the page and are not animated. The layout is setup with a vertical accordion menu on a left bar, content and transparent pngs are located in the column to the right on the menu column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was a machine specific problem. I'm testing on a brand new iMac (2.8 ghz intel i5) and when I tested it on my co-workers laptop that had more RAM the site ran just fine, I have 4MB of RAM on this computer which I would hope was enough. I'm going to test on a few more machines.